# How to detach from terminal so that post-receive hook in git finalizes

Tags: c++, bash, git, githooks

i'm creating a post-receive hook for my deploy repository.
The hook compiles and executes my program. The programm outputs a few lines i'd like to see, forks and only continues in the forked process.
When i start the program with `2>&1 1>/dev/null &` it works fine, although i don't see any output from that. I tried calling `setsid()` after fork, but then the git commit doesn't stop, it continues outputting the program output.

Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: what is the forked process is it the background process which should run forever ? when the caller can continue to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fork your program; both of them have access to the stdout/err stream; which the git hook is more than likely awaiting to close.

To resolve your issue; If your forked process that continues, closes its handle to stdout, stderr, and stdin;

```
close(fileno(stdin));
close(fileno(stdout));
close(fileno(stderr));
```

as well as starting the new session `setsid()` (which you did) it will become a completely detached process from your soon to be dead process.

Note that attempting to output anything afterwards will be undefined behaviour if left as is.

If you wanted to continue to use only `cout` or `cerr` in that process, I would suggest you redirect it using `rdbuf` as you could at that point after forking, redirect the stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`

If you wanted to use `printf` or any of it's family, then you would have to re-bind the stdout file descriptor to something.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what i needed.

Comment: For a post-receive hook in particular, there is no need to close stdin as it refers to a pipe on which Git has written the updated references (and then closed the write end of that pipe). For more general cases of something run by ssh, it's appropriate to detach all three like this, though.

Comment: @torek which is why I said they both had access to the stdout/err which git is waiting for them to close - but yes, stdin probably doesn't need to be closed here  (but it does make the intentions very clear!)  ;)

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. If you are starting the subprocess from Python with Popen, passing `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` is sufficient according to my tests.